# What is the position of women in current (early 2022) Afghan society?

Tags: education, afghanistan, feminism

As of 2022, the Taliban managed to take over Afghanistan approximately half a year ago. I would like to know more about the current situation over there. To be precise, I've read that women under the Taliban leadership don't have access to education in the same way men do. Does that still stand? How are women in Afghanistan treated in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taliban is [strongly against](https://www.usip.org/publications/2022/04/talibans-ban-girls-education-afghanistan) comprehensive education for girls. They are also against any education or permission to hold positions of influence for grown-up women.

However, they were willing to make some compromises. These involve permitting [basic literacy education for girls up to 6th grade](https://www.npr.org/2022/03/23/1088202759/taliban-afghanistan-girls-school). The Taliban also considered it acceptable to [permit women in college to finish their studies](https://www.npr.org/2021/09/12/1036485673/taliban-rule-afghanistan-women-gender-segregated-universities).

That still stands. Women in Afghanistan under Taliban, very different from Afghanistan's pre-theocracy days, are treated as existing for reproductive purposes. Knowledge that doesn't serve this purpose is considered an unnecessary and undesirable distraction.

Taliban has previously promised that women already corrupted by education could be allowed to proceed in their work duties. However, in practice, it proceeded to [suspend their employment](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2021/12/1/talibans-ban-on-women-in-the-workforce-can-cost-economy-1bn) where possible.